# Access user's geolocation using slack API

Tags: node.js, geolocation, slack, slack-api

I have a Slack bot built using slack nodejs SDK. I have a requirement to get the user's geolocation data/lat-long coordinates or a way to get the current location of the user.

Does slack provide any API or something that gives me geolocation data of the user?

If not, then any suggestion for a workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Slack does not provide any location related data.

I suggest dropping a mail to slack directly for your specific use-case.